# why does my API route in next.js is giving 404 error

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, sanity

why does my fetch request gives me the error "GET http://localhost:3000/api/db/getRideTypes 404 (Not Found)" when trying to fetch data from sanity client.

The partial code of Rideselector.js is

```
//"use client";

import Image from 'next/image'
import ethLogo from '../assets/eth-logo.png'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const style = {
    wrapper: `h-full flex flex-col`,
    title: `text-gray-500 text-center text-xs py-2 border-b`,
    carList: `flex flex-col flex-1 overflow-scroll`,
    car: `flex p-3 m-2 items-center border-2 border-white`,
    selectedCar: `border-2 border-black flex p-3 m-2 items-center`,
    carImage: `h-14`,
    carDetails: `ml-2 flex-1`,
    service: `font-medium`,
    time: `text-xs text-blue-500`,
    priceContainer: `flex items-center`,
    price: `mr-[-0.8rem]`,
}

const basePrice = 15530

const RideSelector = () => {
    const [carList, setCarList] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        ;(async () => {
          try {
            const response = await fetch('api/db/getRideTypes')
            
            const data = await response.json()
            setCarList(data.data)
            
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
          }
        })()
    }, [])
```

The getRideTypes.js is

```
import { client } from "../../../../../lib/sanity"

const query = `
*[_type=="rides"]{
    "service": title,
    "iconUrl": icon.asset->url,
    priceMultiplier,
    orderById
}|order(orderById asc)
`

const getRideTypes = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const sanityResponse = await client.fetch(query)
      console.log(sanityResponse)
  
      res.status(200).send({ message: 'success', data: sanityResponse })
    } catch (error) {
      
      res.status(500).send({ message: 'error', data: error.message })
    }
}
export default getRideTypes
```

The getRideTypes.js is inside the api folder which has the structure of src/app/pages/api/db/getRideTypes.js. src is in the root. RideSelector.js is in the components folder that is in the root directory same as the src folder.

Answer (score 1):

The request path is invalid, the correct path would be `/api/db/getRideTypes`. Also uncomment the `"use client";` directive at the top of the ride selectors file because you are using state in that component.

Comment: No it does not work. Still gives the same 404 (Not Found) error as before. Is there something wrong with my file structure?